# What does XmlSerializer use to compile assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xmlserializer

What utility, I assume command line, does `XmlSerializer` use to generate the temporary assembly when constructing an instance of the `XmlSerializer` class?

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
```

In this constructor `XmlSerializer` uses something to compile a temporary assembly in this constructor, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the built-in C# code compiler using the [`CSharpCodeProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) (which eventually calls [`csc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)).

The existence of `System.CodeDom.Compiler` in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs,292c7197dcb706a1) does indicate that.

Some digging revealed [this line that shows the compiler](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/Compiler.cs,160).

Answer (score 0):

none, it used reflection exclusively in the last implementation I checked out.

FYI - implementation was changed in .Net 4.5.1 which broke lot's of my web services :(

what version of .Net are you running your app on?

Comment: It has to compile the assembly. It uses the C# compiler.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the last implementation you checked? Questions doesn't answer the question and doesn't provide any benefit for future readers so try to move them to comments to the actual question instead. Also, IMO personal anecdotes doesn't help much. It's a good addition that it has changed, but the fact that it broke your web services could be skipped.

Comment: 1) reimplemented, 2) breaking changes, 3) versions <4.5 didn't recompile into a new assembly at runtime

Answer (score 0):

There are two serialization tools that the generator uses. Here is a reference to it in MSDN.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
I believe you're looking for the

XML Serializer Generator Tool (Sgen.exe)

Comment: No, that is the developer tool. This isn't part of the framework.